# Mathematica solving for a variable t

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to use Mathematica to solve for t in this equation:

```
Sum[Subscript[a, i]E^(-Subscript[g, i]*t), {i, 0, 100}]
```

This will give something like:

```
E^(-t Subscript[g, 0]) Subscript[a, 0] + E^(-t Subscript[g, 1]) Subscript[a, 1] + .....
```

This summation is equal to certain value x.

I know all the values of `Subscript[a, i]` and `Subscript[g, i]`.

I also know the final summation value of `x`, but t is not known.

How can I write the input file for Mathematica so that I could get the value of t?

Thank you very much. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Define explicit lists for `a` and `g` (since you say you know all these values) and then instead of using subscripts actually take the values from the lists, like `a[[i]]` and `g[[i]]`.

Then that Sum expression should give you a long but explicit formula, and you can pass that to the `Solve` method, like:

```
Sum[a[[i]]/E^(-g[[i]]*t), {i, 1, 100}]
Solve[% == x, t]
```

I hope this helps.  I unfortunately don't have a working copy of Mathematica on hand to double check the syntax, but I think this should help you get started.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand it but if the value goes from 0 to perhaps 10000 or something, wouldn't the data be hard to process due to the fact that there are so many values?

Comment: It's hard to say…  It might be hard to process or Mathematica might do some clever transform and solve it easily.  Mathematica is kind of opaque that way.  Do you need an exact solution or an approximate solution?  If you just need an approximate solution you might be able to use NSolve instead of Solve.  Again, it's opaque, but the numerical approximation methods are surely going to be less sensitive to the complexity of the input expression than the symbolic solution methods.

Comment: Hello! I tried, but the result give the conditional expression and it seems like Mathematica is unable to produce even the approximate result. Is there a way so that I could provide the program a parameter like [1,10] so that mathematica computes the values within that range and see if any of the numbers in the range fits the value of t? Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Hmm, you could try including an extra argument like "1 <= t && t <= 10" in your call to the solve function.  (Note that 1 <= t <= 10, the way mathematicians write it, will not work because Mathematica will interpret it as (1<=t)<=10, i.e. (True or False)<=10.). Anyway, that inequality will give Mathematica a lot of extra information.  In particular, Mathematica will then know that t is real (and positive) and that could help simplify the expression.